# Working with .off in opengl with normals

Tags: c++, opengl

How can i put the right normals to the object? There is a way to transform from .off into an object that contains normals?

Answer (score 1):

OFF files usually don't support special attributes per face or per vertex and thus have no normals.

The simplest thing you can do is do simply calculate the normals yourself using one of the well-known and easy to implement face-normal algorithms. [Here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal) are a few examples.

Comment: This method worked. But i want to put textures, i mean some colors on the ship. How can i do that? There is another format of object that i can use in opengl to draw ships for examples, with colors on them and normals? Thank you!

Comment: @StanciuAlexandru-Marian OpenGL knows nothing about formats. You have to parse a file yourself and setup the rendering facilities with the information extracted from the file. You can freely use whichever texture you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at doing normals via a texture (aka [bump mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping)). You will basically need to generate a normal map of your models in a 3D program and be using some kind of perpixel shading and bind your shades to use the normal texture.

The advantage to doing it that way is you can have higher detail without increasing the number of polygons. You can do things like generate a single grainy bumpy stone pattern on a single flat polygon.

Also if you generate your normals procedurally you can't mix flat and smooth shading.

Comment: Normal mapping requires a tangent space basis at each vertex, that also contains the normal. Therefore that's not a solution to the question.

Comment: @AxelGneiting: It is perfectly possible to calculate a normal map in model space. Those are quite uncommon these days, but they used to be quite popular before programmable hardware existed.